# 'AS' align plus incbin is not producing the expected alignment

Tags: assembly, memory-alignment, binutils

I'm having problem at making [my personal project](https://github.com/haroldo-ok/vn32x) work on real hardware due to data alignment problems; due to the way the hardware works, the images must by 16-bit aligned.

I have tried to specify the alignment through the '.align' directive:

```
.text
.align 2

.globl _vg_lecturehall
.globl _vg_sylvie_giggle
.globl _vg_club

_vg_lecturehall:
.align 2
.incbin "build/lecturehall.apg"

_vg_sylvie_giggle:
.align 2
.incbin "build/sylvie_giggle.apg"

_vg_club:
.align 2
.incbin "build/club.apg"
```

But, as can be seem by the memory map, the data is still placed at odd addresses:

```
 .text          0x000000000200aa00    0x12aac build/generated_images.o
                0x000000000200aa00                _vg_lecturehall
                0x0000000002012d11                _vg_sylvie_giggle
                0x0000000002014f2b                _vg_club
```

Does anyone have any idea of what is being done wrong?
Is there a way to ensure that a included binary is positioned at an even address?

Comment: The problem is you placed the label before the `.align` directive, you should of course put it between the `.align` and the `.incbin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are placing your labels BEFORE the `.align` directives.  At that point, there is no particular alignment in effect - it will depend on whether the preceding `.incbin` generated an odd or an even number of bytes.  Move the labels down one line, so that you are actually labeling the included data.